# Code Coverage on Windows with proprietary testing automation

Tags: c++, windows, code-coverage, lcov

We have our own test automation software which executes our product exe. We do not have test cases written in C++ but our code is written in C++.

What we want is to run out automation tool on our exe which will run the test suite and then find the lines of code that have been executed (code-coverage).

Is there any way to do the above? Something similar to LCOV?

Comment: Any other pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Semantic Designs' (my company) [C++ Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CppTestCoverage.html) could be used for this for either MS C++ or GCC.

The tool instruments your source code before you compile it.  The compiled binary is executed by whatever means; as it runs, the instrumentation collects test coverage information, and occasionally writes that data to a special file.  That file is then analyzed/displayed by a special UI.

If you can get your automation tool to signal when an individual test is complete (this may happen as a natural "last action" on each test, or by other convention), then the test coverage data can be captured on a per-test basis to give you a finer-grain view of the coverage data.

Comment: I have downloaded the evaluation version, but unable to install "Error reading setup initialization file"

Comment: Contact support@semanticdesigns.com with a specific snapshot of your complaint.